# Angular2 subscribe understand arrow function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, arrow-functions

I try to understand arrow functions of typescript by the example of **Angular 2** Observable subscribe method. Could somebody explain me:

I have this code which works:

```
 this.readdataservice.getPost().subscribe(
            posts => { this.posts = posts; }
        );
```

but should it be the same if I use this? But this doesn't work.

```
this.readdataservice.getPost().subscribe(
            function (posts) {
                this.posts = posts;
            }

        );
```

Comment: Arrow functions are not a typescript feature. It's an ES6 feature supported by Typescript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: If you'd like to know more about scopes, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485

Comment: was searching so much for the same doubt. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JS by default executes functions in the scope of the caller. If you pass a function around to be called somewhere else, `this` points to the caller.
In your code you pass the function to the observable via the `subscribe(...)` method and then the function is called by the observable when an event is to be emitted.

If you use arrow function, then `this` keeps pointing to the class where it is defined.

An alternative is using `.bind(this)` to tell JS `this` should keep pointing at the current class instance.

```
    this.readdataservice.getPost().subscribe(
        function (posts) {
            this.posts = posts;
        }.bind(this)

    );
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 14):

1. Arrow function is anonymous and doesn't bind its own `this`. Hence, `this` is `this` of current context.
2. Normal function binds `this` to the caller if we don't bind it explicitly

---

Then

```
    this.readdataservice.getPost().subscribe(
        posts => { this.posts = posts; }
    );
```

Can be

```
    var self = this;
    this.readdataservice.getPost().subscribe(
        function(posts) { self.posts = posts; }
    );
```

Or

```
    this.readdataservice.getPost().subscribe(
        function(posts) { this.posts = posts; }.bind(this)
    );
```