# How do I call a function within the same class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class

I have two functions within a javascript class and I am trying to call one from inside the other, but it is not working. Why is that?

```
class Grid {

  paintGrid() {
    $("td").on("click", function() {
        var color = $("#colorPicker").val();
        $(this).css( "background-color", color);
    })
  }

  makeGrid() {
    $("#sizePicker").one("submit", function(e) {
        let height = $("#inputHeight").val();
        let width = $("#inputWeight").val();
        var vertical;
        for (var i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
            var vertical = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
                var horizontal = document.createElement("td");
                vertical.append(horizontal);
                $("#pixelCanvas").append(vertical);
            }
        };
        e.preventDefault();
        this.paintGrid();
    })
  }
}

let creation = new Grid();
creation.makeGrid();
```

The thing is: when I replace `this.paintGrid()` for the function inside it, it works. So the error is on how I call it, I believe.

Comment: `this` in the callback refers to `#sizePicker`, not to an instance of the class.

Comment: That's not the issue. Test this code and it works: `class Grid {

  paintGrid() {
    console.log('paintGrid called');
  }

  makeGrid() {
    console.log('makeGrid');
    this.paintGrid();
  }
}

const grid = new Grid();
grid.makeGrid();` .... So it is not the way the function is being called. What @Teemu sayes makes sense.

Comment: You are defining vertical twice.

Comment: @Teemu, yes. The callback definitely is a key aspect here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There 2 solutions for you:

1. Assign `this` to a variable

   ```
   makeGrid() {
      var self = this;
      $("#sizePicker").one("submit", function(e) {
         //...
         self.paintGrid();
      })
   }
   ```
2. Using arrow function

   ```
   makeGrid() {
      $("#sizePicker").one("submit", (e) => {
         //...
         this.paintGrid();
      })
   }
   ```

In javascript function bind `this` to the caller.
Arrow function binds `this` to current context - the class instance in this case.

You can take a look at [Function vs Arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801758/angular2-subscribe-understand-arrow-function/40802056#40802056) for more information