# *ngfor not display any data in Angular7

Tags: angular, angular7, ngfor

I 'm using angular7 , and here is my code :
in component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FocusAreasService } from "../../services/focus-areas.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-about",
  templateUrl: "./about.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./about.component.scss"]
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  public canonical: string;
  public RsFocusArea: any[];
  constructor(public focusareaService: FocusAreasService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.canonical = document.location.origin;

    this.focusareaService.getFocusAreaDataWithHttpClient2().subscribe({
      next(response) {
        console.log("HttpClient handle data");
        console.dir(response);

        this.RsFocusArea = response["focusArea"];
       //I print this.RsFocusArea here , it has values 
        console.log("this.RsFocusArea");
        console.dir(this.RsFocusArea);
      },
      error(err) {
        console.error("Error: " + err);
      },
      complete() {
        console.log("Completed");
      }
    });
  }
}

}
```

and in .html

```html
 <ul class="col-xs-12 row">
        <li *ngFor="let area of RsFocusArea" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">{{area}}
        </li>
      </ul>
```

and the li tage did not repeat and gave me this in tag structure:

```html
<ul _ngcontent-aly-c5="" class="col-xs-12 row"><!--bindings={}--></ul>
<!--bindings={}-->
<ul _ngcontent-aly-c5="" class="col-xs-12 row"><!--bindings={}--></ul>
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? I thought maybe I need to rerender the page when I assign new value to RsFocusArea in ngOnInit?

Comment: `RsFocusArea: [1, 2, 3];` should be `RsFocusArea = [1, 2, 3];`

Comment: thanks for your correction , I have noticed that too . but still not work when I change it to `RsFocusArea = [1, 2, 3];`

Comment: where is .id and .link  defined in RsFocusArea

Comment: You need to use like this way.                                                                                        RsFocusArea = [
    {id:'myid, link:'mylink'},
  ];

Comment: @GaneshGudghe , I delete the redundant code, the problem is it won't repeat the <li> tag , even the RsFocusArea is a hard code array.

Comment: ok now check it will work  check this one 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aphc1x

Comment: Code does not have any issues, may be the classes which you are using might causing some issue. try removing those classes and @GaneshGudghe already put a sample run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem is in the subscription

The thing is that you never set the variable you actually want, the `this.RsFocusArea` from your component never gets a value, the `this.RsFocusArea` variable you call in your subscription is in the scope of the `next(response){}` function.

---

Using `next(response){...}` in your `subscribe()` will cause the `this` keyword to reference the `next(response){}` function, meaning `this.RsFocusArea` doesn't refer to your component's variable anymore, but it's looking for an undefined variable instead.

*(Explained here: [Angular2 subscribe understand arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801758/angular2-subscribe-understand-arrow-function))*

*In short: The `this` keyword can be tricky inside other functions*

#### To fix it:

Try writing your `subscribe` with arrow functions instead:

```
this.focusareaService.getFocusAreaDataWithHttpClient2().subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log("HttpClient handle data");
    console.dir(response);

    this.RsFocusArea = response["focusArea"];
    //I print this.RsFocusArea here , it has values 
    console.log("this.RsFocusArea");
    console.dir(this.RsFocusArea);
  },
  err => {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  },
  () => {
    console.log("Completed");
  }
});
```

If you really want to use the `next()` notation you can have a look at how to bind the function.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
RsFocusArea = [1, 2, 3];
```

In Template :

```
<li *ngFor="let area of RsFocusArea" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
     {{area}}
</li>
```

https://angular-bchmnn.stackblitz.io

Hope, it will solve your problem.

Comment: thank you for your solution , I tried it,  works well. I have updated my question. in real scene, we fetch data from server and assign it to property. for now the hard code works well. but if I fetch data from server , it seems not work again. I printed the data in  next(response) , it's not null. so maybe I should rerender the page after assign data to property?

Comment: Could you please post server response ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh god!, I was writing the answer that Jojofoulk posted here. At least I am going to explain you why this happens in less words. Arrow functions keep the context where they were declared, in the other hand, the function declarations keep a local scope.

When you do this:

```
{
    ...
    this.RsFocusArea = response["focusArea"];
}
```

You are assigning the reponse value in function local scope and the outer scope doesn't result affected and is for that reason when you print the value you see your response, but you are seeing a local result assigned in local scope.